# Must a tacoshi always remain the smallest possible sub unit of Monero?

Tags: monero-terminology

A tacoshi is one trillionth of one Monero and the smallest sub unit available. Where did the name tacoshi originate?

If Monero becomes widely adopted and its value grows dramatically can small Monero units be created? If smaller units are possible, would there creation require a hard fork or a soft fork?

Comment: Tacoshi was proposed not as the atomic unit of monero, but as the equivalent of satoshi for bitcoin (ie, 1e-8 monero), so equivalent to 10k piconero, or 10 nanonero.

Comment: I have always referred to this unit as the: "St. Nick" in honor of Nicholas van Saberhagen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tacoshi was named after a Monero developer called [TacoTime](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=19270).

It would be possible to create units smaller than 0.000000000001 XMR but smaller atomic units would require a hard fork so that those smaller units would be recognized by all peers on the network.

Even if prices rose dramatically the need for smaller units would remain uncertain without more information about current network activity, hash rates and transaction fees.

Comment: Just to give an idea about what "prices rose dramatically" would mean, consider that for the tacoshi to be an economically relevant unit of account, let's say $0.0001 (one-hundredth of a penny USD), the price of 1 XMR would be worth $100M. Since XMR is currently just under $2, that would be a price increase of about 50000000X. Probably not something to worry about for quite some time...

Comment: I think I could deal with that problem.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure the term tacoshi will continue to be used interchangeably, but the official term of piconero was recently merged into the source code.

[See github link here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1826)